# Java highscore list

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

So i have a problem with my final projekt in school. I'm creating a game with a highscore list but i need to have ten people to show up, and i curently only have 5 people and i do not have a single clue how to fix it.

```
import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class HighscoreManager {
        // Sparar alla poäng i filen "scores.dat", filen skapas här
        private static final String HIGHSCORE_FILE = "scores.dat";

        // En arraylista med typen score
        ArrayList<Score> scores;

        // Startar en in och en utström för att skicka och ladda in information från
        // filen
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;

        public HighscoreManager() {
            // För att kunna arbeta med listan behövs en variabel dvs. Arraylistan
            // scores
            scores = new ArrayList<Score>();
            // Det är med classen Arraylist<score> getScores() som arrayen skapas
            // forts
        }

        public ArrayList<Score> getScores() {
            // ...forts-> och här används loadScoreFil() och sort(), returnerar
            // värdet scores som används i HighscoreManager
            loadScoreFile();
            sort();
            return scores;
        }

        private void sort() {
            // Här blir det komplicerat, kort och gott så skapas "comparator", ifrån
            // ScoreComparator.java, den sorterar scores med hjälp av just
            // collections(från java).sort(x,y)
            ScoreComparator comparator = new ScoreComparator();
            Collections.sort(scores, comparator);
        }

        public void addScore(String name, int score) {

            loadScoreFile();
            scores.add(new Score(name, score));
            updateScoreFile();
        }

        public void loadScoreFile() {
            //Se updateScoreFile
            try {
                inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                        HIGHSCORE_FILE));
                scores = (ArrayList<Score>) inputStream.readObject();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("io problem: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("cnf problem: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("io problem: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        public void updateScoreFile() {
            try {
                // Med serializerade Score.java så används outputStream för att
                // skicka till HIGHSCORE_FILE som är scores.dat

                outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                        HIGHSCORE_FILE));
                outputStream.writeObject(scores);
            }
            // resten är catch som kan göras om för att visa felmeddelanden, jag
            // gjorde bara en basic.
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File Not Found, run the program again to fix.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IO problem, run the program again to fix.");
            }

            finally {
                try {
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                        // Detta displayar poängen så länge det finns något att
                        // displaya
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Update problem, run the program again to fix.");
                }
            }
        }

        public String getHighscoreString() {
            // Här skapas själva texten som ska visas, nästan slutstation för
            // highscoret

            // Skapar Stringen highscoreString och sätter en maxgräns för hur många
            // highscores som ska vara med.
            String highscoreString = "";
            int max = 10;

            // Sammanställer poängen
            ArrayList<Score> scores;
            scores = getScores();

            // while loop som printar ut ett highscore i taget, när i < max så
            // skrivs scores1,scores2 etc ut och plussar
            // på i och processen repeteras tills i = x, då returneras värdet som är
            // highscoreString och kan användas i tamain.
            int i = 0;
            int x = scores.size();
            if (x > max) {
                x = max;
            }

            while (i < x) {
                highscoreString += (i + 1) + ".\t" + scores.get(i).getNamn() + "  "
                        + scores.get(i).getScore() + "\n";
                i++;
            }

            return highscoreString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where in your code do you have the top 5 scores? A simple algorithm to get the top N scores: Geth the first N scores, sort them. Take the next score, if it's bigger than the smallest one, remove the smallest one and insert the new score at th right place. And loop till the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a JUnit test for your code and tried writing ten scores to the scores.dat file. I then tried reading the scores.dat file and the list of scores contained 10 scores. Your code seems to be working.

Do you have more than five scores in the scores.dat file ?

I ran the following test:
`public class HighscoreManagerTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTenHighscores(){
        HighscoreManager highscoreManager = new HighscoreManager();
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 2", 998);
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 1", 999);
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 5", 995);
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 3", 997);
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 4", 996);
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 6", 994);
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 7", 993);
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 8", 992);
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 9", 991);
        highscoreManager.addScore("Player 10", 990);
        ArrayList<Score> scores = highscoreManager.getScores();
        System.out.println( highscoreManager.getHighscoreString() );
        Assert.assertEquals( 10 , scores.size() );
    }
}`